# Need to Get the time in correct format from JavaScript to ISODateString?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-format, isodate

Actually i am trying to convert the date from java script date to ISO date format but the time is displayed is incorrect.In this the time is 14:30 but i am  getting 9:30 it should be 2:30.And i need to add 30 min to my time.This function is used to convert JavaScript date To ISO data.

```
function myFunction1()
{
 var val1="2013-08-08 14:30:59";
 var t = val1.split(/[- :]/);
    alert(t);
 d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
 d = new Date(d.getTime() + (30 * 60000));
 alert(ISODateString(d));
}


function ISODateString(d){
      function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
      return d.getUTCFullYear()+'-'
          + pad(d.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'
          + pad(d.getUTCDate()) +' '
          + pad(d.getUTCHours())+':'
          + pad(d.getUTCMinutes())+':'
          + pad(d.getUTCSeconds())
    }
```

Share with me please if you know about.I have worked [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/W4xjK/2/)

Comment: Why should it be `2:30` when it is `14:30`?

Comment: It should be because Date is created in GMT whereas your local timezone is IST. So 14:30 gets converted to 09:00 GMT + 30 minutes (= 09:30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for UTC and therefore remove it.

Basically what you're looking for is (converting to 12 hrs time format)

```
pad(d.getHours() > 12 
              ? d.getHours() - 12 : d.getHours())
```

Complete Code:

```
function ISODateString(d) {
    function pad(n) {
        return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n
    }
    return d.getFullYear() + '-' + pad(d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' 
          + pad(d.getDate()) + ' ' + pad(d.getHours() > 12 
          ? d.getHours() - 12 : d.getHours()) 
          + ':' + pad(d.getMinutes()) + ':' + pad(d.getSeconds())
}
```

> **Result:**
>
> ***input:*** 2013-08-08 14:30:59
>
> ***output:*** 2013-08-08 03:00:59  //Since you increased 30 mins

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/W4xjK/4/)

Comment: @InderSingh I'm Glad I was able to help :)

Comment: Can you able to convert into 24hr plzz :)

Comment: @InderSingh try this `pad(d.getHours())` like `return d.getFullYear() + '-' + pad(d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + pad(d.getDate()) + ' ' + pad(d.getHours()) + ':' + pad(d.getMinutes()) + ':' + pad(d.getSeconds())`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're parsing the input in your locale timezone, but outputting the ISO string in UTC time. If the input is UTC as well, you need to use [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC):

```
function myFunction1() {
    var val1="2013-08-08 14:30:59";
    var t = val1.split(/[- :]/);
    alert(t);
    var d = Date.UTC(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
    d = new Date(d + (30 * 60000));
    alert("toISOString" in d ? d.toISOString() : ISODateString(d));
    //     if available then use native method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date('2013-08-08 14:30:59');
var hours = ((date.getHours() + 11) % 12 + 1);
var minutes = date.getMinutes();

console.log(hours+':'+minutes);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N5LDB/